# how to insert a date series in postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, date, series

I want to insert a Date series into an existing table (**public.test**) in the column(**day**) starting from 2015-04-01 ,2015-04-02 ,.....to 2015-04-30.i know there is a generate series method in postgreSQL.But Can I generate dates using that or is there any other method to generate Dates?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `generate_series('2015-04-01'::date,'2015-04-30'::date,'1 day'::interval)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

smth like

```
insert into public.test ("day") 
select generate_series('2015-04-01'::date,'2015-04-30'::date,'1 day'::interval);
```

should work

Comment: Worked like a charm!