# generate sequence of dates in SQL for each variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with three recipes and dates those recipes appear on the menu:

```
CREATE TABLE recipes (
  recipe_id INT NOT NULL,
  recipe_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  recipe_date DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id)
);

INSERT INTO recipes 
    (recipe_id, recipe_name, recipe_date) 
VALUES 
    (1,'Tacos', to_date('2018-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
    (2,'Tomato Soup', to_date('2018-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
    (3,'Grilled Cheese', to_date('2018-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
    (4,'Tacos', to_date('2018-09-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
    (5,'Tomato Soup', to_date('2018-10-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
    (6,'Grilled Cheese', to_date('2018-11-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

My goal is to generate a series of dates that increments by one day for each recipe's `min(recipe_date)` until `date(now())` and using that create a two-column table which contains the `recipe_id` and series of dates.

That means if today's date is `2018-11-07`, there will be a total of
**113 rows** :

(68 days generated for Tacos, 38 days generated for Tomato Soup, and 7 days generated for Grilled Cheese)

How would one, in psql, generate a table containing a series of dates starting from the min for each `recipe_id` variable? Would this be with a `CROSS JOIN` ?

Comment: mysqli -> MySQL, psql -> PostgreSQL.  Which is it?  This is considerably easier in PostgreSQL, BTW.

Comment: PostgreSQL then

Comment: I'm just confused about to do this `for each` type of query in psql using a generate date sequence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert a date series in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220822/how-to-insert-a-date-series-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSql you can actually get those dates via a Recursive [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html)

Test [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/07fb3/2/0) on SQL Fiddle.

```
with RECURSIVE RECIPEDATES (recipe_date, recipe_name) AS
(
  select min(recipe_date), recipe_name
  from recipes
  group by recipe_name

  union all

  select recipe_date + 1, recipe_name
  from RECIPEDATES
  where recipe_date <= current_date
)
select recipe_name, recipe_date
from RECIPEDATES
order by recipe_name, recipe_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you would use `generate_series()`:

```
select r.recipe_id, gs.dte
from (select recipe_id, min(date) as mind, max(date) as maxd
      from recipes
      group by recipe_id
     ) r cross join lateral
     generate_series(mind, maxd, interval '1 day') as gs(dte)
order by r.recipe_id, gs.dte;
```